# Class ' cannot be indexed because it has no default property

Tags: vb.net

I get the following error `Class 'PropGenie_WebService.Branch' cannot be indexed because it has no default property.` And I am not sure why. I have googled but don't get a proper explanation or fix. C# help welcome.

My code in the branch.vb class:

```
Public Function Update() As Branch
    Return Update(Me, Path) 'error at update.
End Function
```

And in my Base class (Resources.vb) I have:

```
Public Shared Function Update(Of T As {Resources, New})(resource As T, path As String) As T
        Dim request = CreateRequest(path & "/{id}", Method.PATCH)
        request.AddUrlSegment("id", resource.Id.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        request.AddBody(resource)
        Dim Client = CreateClient()
        Dim responce = Client.Execute(Of T)(request)
        If responce.StatusCode <> HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Throw New InvalidOperationException("Update Failed" & Convert.ToString(responce.StatusCode))
        End If
        Return responce.Data
    End Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify the class in which the shared function is also, or it will try to use the `Update` function in the object you are in.

```
Public Function Update() As Branch
    Return Resources.Update(Me, Path)
End Function
```